# Core data doesn't save to sqlite database

Tags: ios, sqlite, core-data

I have tried to search an answer but nothing helped me(
So I try to save data in core data ios like this

```
-(void) insertHeaderCatalogsToDataBase{

    UBCoreDataStack *coreDataStack = [UBCoreDataStack defaultStack];
    UBMenuHeader *menuHeader = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"UBMenuHeader" inManagedObjectContext:coreDataStack.managedObjectContext];
    menuHeader.name = @"Комплекты";
    [coreDataStack saveContext];

}
```

UBCoreDataStack - is an singleton class that was cutted from delegate to this class.

```
@interface UBCoreDataStack : NSObject

+(instancetype) defaultStack;

@property (readonly, strong, nonatomic) NSManagedObjectContext *managedObjectContext;
@property (readonly, strong, nonatomic) NSManagedObjectModel *managedObjectModel;
@property (readonly, strong, nonatomic) NSPersistentStoreCoordinator *persistentStoreCoordinator;

- (void)saveContext;
- (NSURL *)applicationDocumentsDirectory;

@end
```

So when I try to save there no errors, and hasChanges returns true

```
- (void)saveContext
{
    NSError *error = nil;
    NSManagedObjectContext *managedObjectContext = self.managedObjectContext;
    if (managedObjectContext != nil) {
        if ([managedObjectContext save:&error] == NO) {
            NSLog(@"Error saving: %@\n%@", [error localizedDescription], [error userInfo]);
        }
        if([managedObjectContext hasChanges]){
            NSLog(@"There are some changes");
        }
        if ([managedObjectContext hasChanges] && ![managedObjectContext save:&error]) {
            // Replace this implementation with code to handle the error appropriately.
            // abort() causes the application to generate a crash log and terminate. You should not use this function in a shipping application, although it may be useful during development.
            NSLog(@"Unresolved error %@, %@", error, [error userInfo]);
            abort();
        }
    }
}
```

When I open folder with sqlite database DBname.sqlite doesn't have any changes, but sqlite-shm and sqlite-wal has. So may be I forgot something to pass values to sqlite DB

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, data was on place. It is normal that sqlite doesn't have any changes, but sqlite-shm and sqlite-wal has.